# c struct size with void * value members

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct in C like this:

```
struct ll {
    struct ll * next; 
    void *value [];
}
```

when I printf the size of `struct ll` as `printf("sizeof ll:%d\n", sizeof(struct ll));`, why is the result 8?

[image]

And what's the meaning of `void *value[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` field is a **flexible array member**.  It is defined as an array of unspecified size of `void *` as the last member of a struct.

C allows this so that you can allocate space for the struct along with and number of elements for the array.  As such, the size of the struct **does not** include the flexible array member.  This is why the size of the struct is 8, as it only include the `next` member.

Suppose you wanted and instance of this struct to have `value` contain 10 elements.  You would then allocate it as follows:

```
struct ll *inst = malloc(sizeof(struct ll) + (sizeof(void *) * 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct ll {
    struct ll * next; 
    void *value [];
};
```

You declare a struct with a `struct ll *` pointer and a flexible array member.
Flexible array members do not add any size to the struct except maybe additional padding.

The size `8` is the size of the struct pointer.

Comment: Yes,you answers is right.